# Taking power of element of finite field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Let $\mathbb{F_{q^n}}$ be a finite field.

Assume $a , b \in  \mathbb{F_{q^n}}$.

Is there any meaning to the power operation: $a^b$?

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not.  As some evidence that there is no natural way to define it, note that for instance, in $\mathbb{F}_3$, you would expect $2^{1+1+1}=2^1\cdot 2^1\cdot 2^1=2\cdot 2\cdot 2=2$ and also $2^{1+1+1}=2^0=1$.

In general, in a ring $R$, the exponentiation operation $a^n$ is defined if $a\in R$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (*not* for $n\in R$): you can recursively define $a^0=1$ and $a^{n+1}=a\cdot a^n$.  If $a$ is a unit, you can extend this to $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ by defining $a^n=b^{-n}$ when $n$ is negative, where $b$ is the multiplicative inverse of $a$.

Comment: First-thanks for the quick answer. But n=3 is not an element in the field $F_3$. So, your conterexample seems a little bit strange, and I asked about finite fields and not rings.  What if I assume an order of the elements in the field of $F_{q^n}$ maybe that will work out?

Comment: My example shows that there can be no definition of exponentiation on $\mathbb{F}_3$ which has the usual expected properties of exponentiation.  You certainly _can_ define exponentiation in some other way if you want to, but I don't know why you would want to or why you would think it deserves the name "exponentiation".